# Sum groupwise but using only individual's first entry

Tags: r

Consider the following sample data. The data has 2 individuals per group and each individual has 2 entries.

```
rm(list=ls()); set.seed(1234)
G=4 ; # Suppose you have 4 groups
nTot<-8 # We have 2 individuals per group so in total we have 8 individuals 
group<-rep(1:G, rep(4,G) )#Group identifier
individualID<-rep(1:nTot, rep(2,nTot) )#We have 2 individuals per group each with 2 entries

n<-2*nTot  # We have 16 entries in total
X<-rbinom(n, 1, 0.5)
Y<-runif(n, 0, 1)
Z<-runif(n, 0, 4)

df1<-round(data.frame(group,individualID,X,Y,Z),3)
> df1
  group individualID X     Y     Z
1      1            1 0 0.286 1.219
2      1            1 1 0.267 2.029
3      1            2 1 0.187 0.724
4      1            2 1 0.232 3.039
5      2            3 1 0.317 0.805
6      2            3 1 0.303 1.035
7      2            4 0 0.159 3.969
8      2            4 0 0.040 3.229
9      3            5 1 0.219 2.213
10     3            5 1 0.811 2.586
11     3            6 1 0.526 1.247
12     3            6 1 0.915 2.487
13     4            7 0 0.831 1.319
14     4            7 1 0.046 2.008
15     4            8 0 0.456 2.708
16     4            8 1 0.265 1.940

Func<-X*Y+Z
Func
```

The code below computes sum of Func per group using split() function.

```
Func<-X*Y+Z
GroupSum<-as.numeric( sapply( split(Func,group),sum)  ) # Group sum of X*Y+Z
```

I would like a code that will split the data and **group sum** Func only for the first entry per individual i.e I should end up with a vector of 4 values as we have 4 groups.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use a group by approach i.e. grouped by 'group', `slice` the first row, `ungroup`, and then `summarise` to get the `sum` of `X` multiplied by 'Y' and added to 'Z'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   slice_head(n = 1) %>%   
   summarise(out = sum(X * Y + Z, na.rm = TRUE))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  group   out
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  2.19
2     2  1.31
3     3  1.50
4     4  2.52
```

---

Or can use `duplicated` in `base R`

```
aggregate(out ~ group, transform(subset(df1, !duplicated(group)), 
       out = X * Y + Z), FUN = sum)
  group   out
1     1 2.194
2     2 1.311
3     3 1.501
4     4 2.522
```

Comment: This helps but however it computes sum of first entry for the whole dataset (all groups).
```
with(subset(df1, !duplicated(individualID) ), sum(X * Y + Z, na.rm = TRUE))
```
Required is to obtain sum of first entries per group.

Comment: @JohnMajimboni It is the sum of first entries per group because `!duplicated` removes the duplicate entires

Comment: @JohnMajimboni what about the dplyr one, i.e. if you remove the `ungroup`, it will be by group

Comment: The data has 2 individuals per group. Each individual has 2 entries (in total I have 4 entries per group). Use of !duplicated(individualID)  removes the duplicates entries per individual. The challenge is how to compute sum of first entries of the 2 individuals per group. I have 4 groups so should end up with  4 values of output.

Comment: @JohnMajimboni that is why I said the first solution works, if you remove the `ungroup`

Comment: The updated solution works.